# could I bind styles to this in react-native

Tags: react-native

I notice all Facebook react-native samples code define `styles` outside class like below way.

```
styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
});

class Foo extends Component {
  render: {
    return (
      /* use styles here */
    );
  }
}
```

I'm newbie to use `node.js` and I don't exactly know when this `styles` object free from memory, so by the simple way, if I define `styles` inner class, binding to this, could it be better?

```
class Bar extends Component {

  constructor() {
    this.styles = StyleSheet.create({
      ...
    });
  }

  render: {
    return (
      /* use this.styles here */
    );
  }
}
```

if possible, maybe some suggestion is enough :)

thanks for your time.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? I would suggest sticking to the first way

Comment: @dv3  thanks for your reply, I wonder when `styles` free if stick first way?  In my opinion, I can control the life cycle if I bind `styles` to `this`, at least it could be recycle in `componentWillUnmount` step I guess.